# What is the proof in FLP for statement that "clique with majority of processes exist" if majority of the processes live?

Tags: distributed-systems, consensus

The [FLP paper](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/papers/Lynch/jacm85.pdf) provides proof in section "4. Initially Dead Processes" that consensus is possible if majority of processes live and no process dies during the consensus protocol. The proof has 4 main steps:

1. Build G graph in way that each process broadcast it's process number and waits for the message from L other processes (L=[(N+1)/2])
2. Calculate transitive closure of G: G+
3. Determine clique of G+. The paper says that clique has cardinality at least L. (Node k is in the clique iff k is itself an ancestor of every
   node j that is an ancestor of k)
4. Make a decision based on the initial values of the processes in the clique

**I would have the following question about step 3:**

- What guarantees that clique described in step 3 exist?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we need to prove that `G` is a single connected component. If `n` is a node in a connected component of `G`, then there are `L-1` other nodes that are also in that component (the ones from which `n` received their messages). So this component has the size of at least `(L-1)+1 = L` nodes. So each connected component has at least `L` number of nodes and `L` is bigger than the half of the number of the nodes, so can be a single connected component only.

By the definition of the transitive closure, `G+` will also have a single connected component. This means that it has only a single initial click. An initial click is a set of nodes that does not have incoming edges. Let's assume that `n` is a member of the initial click of `G+`. Let `m` be another node such that there is an edge from `m` to `n` in `G`. By definition, there is an edge in `G+` from `m` to `n` as well. Because of the definition of initial click, there cannot be an incoming edge to `n` from outside of the initial click, so `m` must be in the initial click as well. By the construction rules of `G`, there is `L-1` number of such `m` nodes that has an edge to `n` in `G`, so they are also part of the initial click along with `n`. So the initial click has the size of at least `L` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It can be proven with the following two steps that clique with cardinality at least L exist:

1. There is at least one node which is in the clique of G+
2. If a node is in the clique of G+ than all of its predecessors are in the clique

For #1 we use proof by contradiction. So we will assume that no such node exist which is ancestor of all its ancestor:

1. If no such node exist than for each node X there is at least one node Y that X is not ancestor of Y in G+
2. If X is not ancestor of Y in G+ than it can not be predecessor of Y predecessors in G either
3. So X can not be the predecessor of the L -1 predecessors of Y and Y itself in G
4. There are L-1 nodes left in G. It includes X so X can have maximum L-2 nodes predecessor
5. If each X has maximum L-2 predecessors in G it means that each node has maximum L-2 outgoing edges. It is contradiction because each node has L-1 incoming edges in G

For #2 the proof is the following with node X which is in the clique of G+:

1. For each Y node in G+ where X is the ancestor of Y than each Z ancestor of X is also ancestor of Y
2. For each Z it is true that its ancestors are subset of X ancestors